# Why does my SVG Logo disappears when wrapping with a tag?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, svg

So I am trying out Bootstrap 4 (realise it is in alpha) but every time I wrap a SVG in a tag it completely disappears?

I am new to using SVG wondering if I need to handle linking them another way.

Currently just doing the usual:

```
<a href="www.somesite.com"><img src="image.svg"></a>
```

Comment: Please add a [mcve] to the question.

Comment: probably because anchor tags are inline and not inline-block

Comment: Added display block to image in css and that sorted it. Thanks Stephen.

Comment: Note that you will run into some cross-browser issues if you don’t specify the height and width attributes ;) https://thatemil.com/blog/2014/04/06/intrinsic-sizing-of-svg-in-responsive-web-design/

Comment: Note that you will run into some cross-browser issues if you don’t specify the height and width attributes ;) https://thatemil.com/blog/2014/04/06/intrinsic-sizing-of-svg-in-responsive-web-design/